# Java Frame (Awt) does not appear on program execution in centos

Tags: java, linux, centos, awt, x11

I made a simple AWT program and made it as a jar file using eclipse on windows machine. After making jar, i sent it to my Centos virtual machine and used ssh to login. When i tried to execute the program, it provides no reply.

I installed Xvfb in Centos and set the DISPLAY variable as well.
X11 forwarding is also enabled on PUTTY

### Java code:

```
public class TestAWT{

    TestAWT()
    {
         JFrame test = new JFrame();
         test.setVisible(true);
         test.setSize(100,100);
         test.setResizable(false);
         test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new TestAWT();
    }
}
```

### Execution command:

```
java -jar testawt.jar
java -jar -Djava.awt.headless=true testawt.jar  -> Throwed Headless Exception
```

Could some please advise how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Headless means that there is no console attached to your program, but you are running Java in this mode.  Remove the

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When i remove it and execute the program, i dont see any response. My program just halts

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a tiny window in the top left of your screen?  Try changing the size to 1000x1000 and check again.